# Exporting fonts?

Tags: mesh, export

I was just wondering - Does Blender currently have any way of exporting meshes into a font file (such as .ttf)? And if not, are there any known plugins that allow this?

Otherwise, I think this would be a great suggestion, because a lot of the text in logos that I make is actually hand-drawn, and even though I am experienced at drawing text in Blender, I can't seem to properly make a font in actual font softwares (such as FontForge). My avatar is a good example of what I can do in Blender without fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender doesn't really enable you to directly export to fonts, but you can integrate it into a font creation pipeline by [rendering your creations to SVG using freestyle](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/Freestyle), then using inkscape to [import the SVGs and export the fonts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KX-e6sijGE). Here's [another method](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/inkscape/ss/Fontastic.htm) that utilizes Inkscape and a font creation website.

[The video in the 2nd link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KX-e6sijGE) also mentions some rules your SVG paths have to obey to work well as font type.

Comment: Alright, interesting - I'll actually be saving a link to this somewhere for safe-keeping and for later reference. Very helpful! Although, it would be nice if Blender did come out with a plugin that allowed font exports... Someone should send a message to them.

Comment: @ob103ninja It would be best to have a independent dev do it (official devs have higher priority/greater difficulty), but yes.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Who would you suggest I'd have a better chance at contacting, maybe?

Comment: @ob103ninja I really do not know. You will probably have to ask around a bit. Make sure you have a good, clear, well thought out proposal. It will help a lot.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Thanks - I will consider making a YouTube video about it. Someone might see it if I share it around.